# HeidiSQL different SQL result on Windows XP (SP2)

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I'm doing application development on VB.net. calculated date field was not display on screen. Testing directly on heidisql returned null value on Windows XP. I know the OS was not supported, but we have certain legacy app that need to run on XP.

[image: heidisql on XP]

while testing on windows 7, the calculated field  was displayed accordingly.

[image: heidisql on Windows 7 32 bit]

Comment: Do you connect to the same database server from both OS? Which DBMS product **are** you using (HeidiSQL is just a SQL client that connects to a DBMS)

Comment: sorry, didn't mention it earliear. i'm using mysql 5.5 (XP) and mysql 5.7 (Win7).

Comment: You should search the differences in the two databases, not in the SQL client.

Comment: You're correct. I did test on both DB version. 5.5 return null. Does it mean mysql 5.5 did not support INTERVAL for TIME datatype ?

Comment: You are running different queries on two physically different servers with different versions, but you expect the same result? You should first use the exactly same query, then narrow the differences down to one value. And you should just post one value / difference here, not a screenshot with a whole result grid.